# Assigning color on Creating Stacked Column chart with xlsxwriter Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I was successfully able to generate  Stacked Column charts in the newly created Excel sheet using pandas dataframe with xlsxwriter of Python Pandas.  But, I can't figure out how to assign color yet.

Here is the picture. 
[image: Stacked Column Chart created with xlsxwriter]

This is from Pandas xlsxwriter documentation. In the given picture, each "Metric" has different colors. For Example, Metric 8 is pink and Metric 1 is blue. I want to assign specific colors to each metric in this example. Obviously, each metric belongs to each row of data in question.

I understand I can do this in excel individually. But, I am writing Python code to generate several dozens of stacked column charts and put it in excel using xlsxwriter. So, it is not practical to do this by hand.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: [The documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html#chart-class) shows a few options for manipulating colors of chart elements.  I'm sure someone on SO would be able to help you figure out how to do it if you provided some of your code.

Comment: Hey @nyan314sn iteratively how are you assigning colors to the stacks. In my case the color is just applied to the last series.

Comment: It has been a long time since I did this. But, the following is what I found in one of my old codes. It might or might note be what you need.             

You got to do chart.add_series one by one for each row of dataframe. The key words I used are "name","categories", "values", "border", "fill" , "gap"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `fill` color for the series.

See the following Pandas-XlsxWriter [stacked charts with colors example](http://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart_stacked_column_farms.html). The example uses brew colors but you can replace those with any [Html like RGB color](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_colors.html).

See also the [XlsxWriter Chart documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html) and [Working with Charts](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html) which explain the API and give examples of setting the colors of different properties.

Comment: Thank you so much...  I didn't realize earlier that I can set the color of each series using "chart.add_series"